# How to enable copy button to copy linebreaks

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, copy, clipboard

Here is my function:

```
function copyFunction(val, event) {
    var inp = document.createElement("input");
    document.body.appendChild(inp)
    inp.value = val;
    inp.select();
    document.execCommand("copy", false);
    inp.remove();
    alert('copied');
}
```

I am able to copy lines of text as long as there are no linebreaks in between. Is there a way to allow copy of linebreaks?

e.g.

```
<button onclick="copyFunction('I am able to copy this example.')">Copy</button></td>

<button onclick="copyFunction('I cannot copy
 this kind of
 example.')">Copy</button></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because your html code isn't valid the way you wrote it. If you set a linebreak you need to close your text off with a " ' " . Try my snippet below and you'll get a better idea of what I mean.

```js
function copyFunction(val) {
  var inp = document.createElement("input");
    document.body.appendChild(inp)
    inp.value = val;
    inp.select();
    document.execCommand("copy", false);
    inp.remove();
    alert('copied');
    alert(val);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="copyFunction('I am able to copy this example.')">Copy</button></td>
<button onclick="copyFunction('I cannot copy \n\r' +
 'this kind of \n\r' +
 'example.')">Copy</button>
```

Comment: But that copies it into 1 line. I want it to appear the way it is when copied so the output result should be:

"I cannot copy \n
this kind of \n
example"

Comment: @Lloyd ahh sorry I misunderstood the question I edited my snippet can you check if this fits your needs?